# How to change Public DNS in amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created an instance in Amazon ec2 and deployed my apps in that.

Now I am able to access my applications using the public dns.

My default public dns is like ec2**********compute-1.amazonaws.com.

How can I change this to some good name like srinivas.com?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Register your domain (i.e. go to a domain registrar and purchase the domain srinivas.com before someone else does)
- Get an elastic IP address from amazon
- assign the elastic IP address to your instance through the aws management interface
- Point your domain to your elastic IP address using your registrar's DNS tools

Comment: Thanq very much . How can i assign the elastic IP address to my instance through the aws management interface

Comment: is there any charges(price) for that or Free.Please help me

Comment: does this work ?? i still get the reverse dns as ec2..ip_addr.location... as my dns. i'm sending emails through my instance and it shows sent by ec2..ip_addr...etc

Answer (score 0):

Forward DNS and Reverse DNS are two completely different things.

No matter what you do in your DNS it resolves to whatever the owner of that ip segment says it does.

Think about it as DNS in Reverse. so say for foo.stackoverflow.com you first query the root .com domain for the stackoverflow NS, then query that NS for the foo A. say 192.168.1.1

But there is no way to make that jump in reverse. nothing will take you from 192.168.1.1 to the NS for the stackoverflow.com domain. You need a completely different lookup, but now looking at IP ranges instead of domains.

in AWS case you need to fill out this form, here: https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

They will change it on their end to point to your A record, this is normally needed for mail servers, therefore the email limit request. just ignore that part and complete the bottom portion of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can request the PTR record to be removed. Do this if you are not using an elastic IP address.

But do get the elastic IP address if you run 24x7 or you expect to shut down.
Shutting down without an elastic IP will just bring you back to square one.