# How to add CName (alias) to amazon ec2 web server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Following the instructions in [How to change Public DNS in amazon ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899887/how-to-change-public-dns-in-amazon-ec2), I could change public DNS in amazon ec2 (ubuntu image).

What I need to do is to add CName (alias) so that `wiki.XYZ.com` points to `/var/www/html/wiki`.

I use godaddy for DNS Zone file, so I added the name `wiki`, and check ping `wiki.XYZ.com` works fine.

[image]

I also modified the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, and restarted apache server with `service apache2 restart`.

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wiki"
ServerName wiki.XYZ.com
# Other directives here                                                         
<Directory "/var/www/html/wiki">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, `wiki.XYZ.com` ends up in error (not page found) in my browser. What might be wrong?

Comment: Is there an index.html file in `/var/www/html/wiki`?  Does the server behave differently if this new apache configuration is absent? (i.e., does it seem to be doing *anything* different)?

Comment: There is an index.html in the directory, and I have the same results without the added configuration.

Comment: n.b. the http://example.com and http://example.org domains are set up for the purpose of masking real domain names with placeholders.  The .com you appear to be using as a placeholder is a real domain, presumably owned by somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my browser (Safari) that searches `wiki.XYZ.com` instead of visiting the site. I had to specify http://wiki.XYZ.com. I don't have this issue with Chrome.

Also, the configuration should be modified as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> <-- specify the port
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wiki"
ServerName wiki.XYZ.com
# Other directives here                                                         
<Directory "/var/www/html/wiki">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should point the Cname to a domain name listed in your A record.
Be sure to read @michael in the comments below.

Comment: This isn't a DNS issue.  Go Daddy's DNS admin tool allows `foo CNAME @` to mean `foo.example.com CNAME example.com`.  (Also, note that CNAMEs can't "point to" IP addresses, only other names).  This is a web server configuration issue.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are correct about the Cname regarding IP addresses; I will edit my answer with your correction.