# change public dns in ec2 to private DNS

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created an instance in Amazon ec2 and deployed.  Now I am able to access my applications using the public dns. My default public dns is like ec2****compute-1.amazonaws.com. How can I change this to some Other Public Dns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Public DNS in amazon ec2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899887/how-to-change-public-dns-in-amazon-ec2)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get an elastic IP address from amazon
2. assign the elastic IP address to your instance through the aws management interface
3. Point your domain to your elastic IP address using your registrar's DNS tools

look this..http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/ and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=289265