# SSH timeout in AWS EC2 Bitnami server

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, timeout, bitnami

I launched Bitnami server in AWS. Earlier we didn't have elastic IP and our dev have done some mess and we attached elastic IP and when trying to login to the server I am getting SSH timeout error. It would be great if someone helps with this.

Thanks.

Comment: How about you just revert the changes? I mean deattach EIP from the server (and reboot?).

Comment: the IP changed..I tried that too..but got same error

Comment: Is Port 22 Open In the Instance security group?

Comment: yes..everything is fine...no firewall too running

Comment: I'd take a look at the logs to see if the SSH service is up and running. If your dev has done some mess in the instance, I don't know if he/she modified the permissions of the SSH files, modified the configuration ... and broke the SSH well-functioning. If you can't access the instance, you can launch a new one and mount the volume of the current one in the new one so you can recover the files of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue on an AWS EC2 instance where I've installed Moodle using Bitnami.

I've followed the following ticket to change my Public DNS in amazon ec2 :
[How to change Public DNS in amazon ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899887/how-to-change-public-dns-in-amazon-ec2)
1 - Register your domain
2 - Get an elastic IP address from amazon
3 - Assign the elastic IP address to your instance through the aws management interface

Before that 3 steps I was able to :

- SSH connect to the instance using Putty;
- open my Moodle site using the public IPv4 address;
- open my Moodle site using the public IPv4 DNS.

After that 3 steps, all the above attemps are failing (time out). But at least I'm able to open my Moodle site with registerd domain.

I was trying to fix my issue with SFTP connection issues (in FileZilla and WinSCP) when I came accross this ticket.

Next steps :

- Roll back the elastic IP assignment to my instance.
- Finish my HTTPS config using SFTP and SSH to transfert and install my certs.
- And reassign the elastic IP.

Note : As I spend the all day on my Moodle site, I'll check this tomorrow!!!

@+
rv.

Comment: Detaching the elastic IP assignment from my instance did not work. Instead the recommendation of Jay about the security group (Ensure that the Security Group for instances allows your IPv4 address for connectivity on port 22) fixed my issue !!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to check here -

1. Security Group- Ensure that the Security Group for instances allows your IPv4 address for connectivity on port 22 (Use https://whatismyipaddress.com/ if you dont know your IP address)
2. Internet Connectivity : Ensure there is Internet connectivity from EC2 instance to internet, ideally it should be a part of private subnet, which uses NAT gateway to send traffic to a public subnet.